# Quais as principais linguagens de programação que integram o SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, característica-linguagem, sqlite3

Quais as principais linguagens de programação que integram o *SQLite* como SGBD em seu código?

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 5):

Nenhuma *mainstream*. [Linguagem de programação](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguagem_de_programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o) é um conjunto de regras para escrever códigos que serão executados pelo computador, então não faz sentido o que foi perguntado.

Mesmo as implementações de linguagens de programação não integram banco de dados. A implementação é fundamentalmente um compilador ou interpretador. Parte do que costuma ser considerado linguagem pelas pessoas é a biblioteca padrão que a acompanha. Neste caso até poderia ter um banco de dados embutido, mas as linguagens mais conhecidas não fazem isto, até porque bibliotecas padrão só deveriam mesmo ter funções mais básicas e universais.

Existem implementações de *bindings* da API do SQLite, que é escrito em C, para diversas linguagens. Aí eu diria que todas as linguagens possuem *bindings* para este banco de dados. Até mesmo algumas linguagens pouco conhecidas e de utilização bem restrita costumam ter acesso à ele. Obviamente devem existir algumas linguagens "estranhas" que não possuem isto pronto.

Na [Wikipedia tem uma pequena lista](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite#Programming_languages), mas poderia citar várias outras não listadas aí.

Pra falar a verdade, isso pouco importa. Escolha a linguagem que é adequada ao seu problema. E se vai usar o SQLite, só verifique se ela possui uma boa implementação para acessar o banco de dados (provavelmente existe).